# mySQL Query result to redirect to different web page

Tags: php, mysql

im currently trying to do a login system. A user has 3 attributes:id, password and a userlevel.  A different webpage will open for different user levels (there are 3 userlevels). I'm not able to implement the third function,I am able to login using id and password alone. Here's the code I have

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="user"; // Database name
$tbl_name="test"; // Table name

$dbcon=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myid=$_POST['id'];
$mypassword=$_POST['pw'];

$myid = stripslashes($myid);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myid = mysql_real_escape_string($myid);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$myid' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem.

Comment: Please consider your users' security and start using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Your code is open to a number of security holes.

Comment: Why do people always recommend mysqli over PDO? mysqli is like subpar compared to PDO.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the user level from the database, and then do an if statement, like so:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$myid' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row['userlevel'] == 1) {
 ....
} elseif ($row['userlevel'] == 2) {
 ....
} elseif ($row['userlevel'] == 3) {
 ....
}
```

Comment: @Keiji is right.  Start to use mysqli.  mysql functions are deprecated in PHP7.

Comment: The [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement called and wanted to have a word with you.